# How to calculate voltage divider between two transistors?

Tags: circuit-analysis, voltage-divider, cmos

I am working on a homework assignment and I don't know what it is but this problem has me stumped. Below is the subsection of the circuit we are supposed to be working with. I don't know if I put in the CMOS transistors correctly, but they are at least the N-type.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdcWPL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

V<sub>T,N</sub> for the transistors is 0.3V. This is the equation I tried to set up to solve this.
$$\frac{1}2\frac{(1V-\Delta V-0.3V)^2}{(1-\Delta V-0.3V)+\Delta V} = \frac{(0.8V-0.3V)^2}{(0.8V-0.3V)+\Delta V}$$

This definitely doesn't work. But I'm not sure what the correct equation should be.

Edit: I guess I'll add that this equation gave me a delta V of about 1.16V. Easy to tell that it is incorrect.

Edit2: I had a mistake in my equation I originally posted.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot about the MOSFET body diodes.

Since both MOSFETs are cut off, and since both diodes are in series-aiding and are foward biased by V1, current from V1 makes its way through both diodes and (if the drop across them is equal) the voltage at the junction of the diodes, DELTA_V, has to be halfway between V1 and ground, as shown below.

[image]
By the way, here's the LTspice circuit list just in case you want to play with the circuit:

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 880 680
WIRE 432 64 224 64
WIRE 480 64 432 64
WIRE 224 80 224 64
WIRE 176 160 96 160
WIRE 480 240 480 64
WIRE 224 256 224 176
WIRE 432 256 224 256
WIRE 96 304 96 160
WIRE 224 304 224 256
WIRE 96 416 96 384
WIRE 224 416 224 384
WIRE 224 416 96 416
WIRE 480 416 480 336
WIRE 480 416 224 416
WIRE 96 464 96 416
FLAG 96 464 0
FLAG 432 64 DELTA_V
SYMBOL nmos 176 80 R0
WINDOW 0 86 32 Right 2
WINDOW 3 159 58 Right 2
SYMATTR InstName Q1
SYMATTR Value IRFH5053
SYMBOL voltage 224 288 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value .8
SYMBOL nmos 432 336 M180
WINDOW 0 -32 59 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -104 34 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName Q2
SYMATTR Value IRFH5053
SYMBOL voltage 96 288 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value 1
TEXT 110 440 Left 2 !.tran 1
```

Comment: I stated in the question that I was not sure that the drawing was correct. My schematic doesn't have the body node. Both of these transistors shouldn't be in cutoff. The Gate of M1 is sitting at 1V. So wouldn't we assume the Drain is at 0.8V and the Source is DeltaV? Which means we can safely assume M1 is on.

Comment: 1. You said, originally: " I don't know if I put in the CMOS transistors correctly", so you were lost from the beginning. 2.Whether your schematic does or does not show the body diodes, they're  still there and need to be considered. 3. Whether the transistors  should or shouldn't be in cutoff isn't a matter of conjecture, it's a matter of fact.  If you can provide some evidence supporting your claim, I'll be the first to back down. Otherwise, regardless of your desire to be right, you aren't.

Comment: If deltaV is 0.4V, then M1 wouldn't be in cutoff correct? Vgs would be 0.6V and deltaV would rise to 0.7V, would it not? I am confused.

Comment: I'm sorry if I am having trouble wording my question and mislead you. I know the function this circuit is performing and I know that these two transistors are not in cutoff.

Comment: @user1362058:  You need to do a few things,  the first being to  download and study the [**IRF530 data sheet**](http://www.vishay.com/docs/91019/91019.pdf), particularly the entry for the gate threshold voltage. The second is to make sure that your schematic is correct, and the third is to download a copy of LTspice, available for free, [**here**](http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/#LTspice) run the code I posted for you in my answer, and probe around to see whether the transistors are cut off or not

Comment: I guess you aren't getting it. The schematic tool provided here doesn't provide the correct items I wanted to place so I just put those two transistors. Ignore them and picture two basic CMOS transistors in their place. I am analyzing the read of a 6T SRAM cell in a special case.

Comment: @user1362058: Regardless of what garden-variety MOSFETs you put in there (as long as they're n-channel enhancement mode MOSFETs with equivalent body diodes) the outcome will be the same. That is, DELTA_V will always be  half of V1, and the transistors will both be cut off.   The schematic tool provided here has a simulator associated with it, so I don't understand why you're arguing instead of getting the data to back up your claims. \$ \style{color:red}{BUT...}\$ all of this is meaningless if the schematic's wiring is wrong, so is it or not?